# Increment Date Object in without converting to epoch in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, epoch

Is it possible to increment a date object by one day without converting the object to an epoch number?

For example the traditional way will convert the date object to an epoch number:

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(today.valueOf()); // copy date object without converting to epoch
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1); // now gets converted to epoch :'(
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

The *set** methods don't "convert to epoch number", they modify the date's internal time value and return the modified value. The date object is still a date.

```js
let today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0); // Start of day
let tvToday = +today;
let tomorrow = new Date(today);
// setDate adjusts the time value and returns it
let tvTomorrow = tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

console.log('Today\'s date: ' + today.toDateString());
console.log('Today\'s time value: ' + tvToday);

console.log('Tomorrow\'s date: ' + tomorrow.toDateString());
console.log('Tomorrow\'s time value: ' + tvTomorrow);

// May vary from 24 by up to 1 hour depending on crossing DST boundaries
console.log('Difference in hours: ' + ((tvTomorrow - tvToday)/3.6e6));
```

If you want a method that adds a day and returns a new Date object, write a function, maybe named *addDays*, that takes a date and number of days to add and returns a new Date object with the days added. Lots of libraries have such functions, they're not hard to write.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that without converting. Maybe convert back after.

```js
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(today.valueOf());

const x = tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
console.log(x) //epoch

const z = new Date(x)
console.log(z.toString())
```

Comment: Because `tomorrow.toString()` was just too short?

Comment: I wrote it that way to make the procedure clear.